# Image Toggle With Fade jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, conditional-statements

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

When I click on the element, I want the img source to toggle between the two specificed images and fade in/out while doing it.

On first click the image transitions fine, but on the second,third,fourth,etc click it keeps serving the same image and not 'toggling' back.

Heres my code

```
$( "#change" ).click(function() {
    var sc = $('#standard-clip');
    if (sc.src = 'images/standard-clips.jpg'){
        $('#standard-clip').fadeOut(300, function(){
            $(this).attr('src','images/clips/standard-back.jpg')
            .bind('onreadystatechange load', function(){
                if (this.complete) $(this).fadeIn(300);
            });
            document.getElementById("color-name").innerHTML = "Back View";
        });
    }
    else{
        $('#standard-clip').fadeOut(300, function(){
            $(this).attr('src','images/standard-clips.jpg')
            .bind('onreadystatechange load', function(){
                if (this.complete) $(this).fadeIn(300);
            });
            document.getElementById("color-name").innerHTML = "Front View";
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$( "#change" ).click(function() {
var sc = $('#standard-clip');
console.log(sc.src);
if (sc.attr("src") == 'http://cdn.embed.ly/providers/logos/jsfiddle.png'){
    $('#standard-clip').fadeOut(300, function(){
        $(this).attr('src','http://doc.jsfiddle.net/_downloads/jsfiddle-logo.png')
        .bind('onreadystatechange load', function(){
            if (this.complete) $(this).fadeIn(300);
        });

    });
}
else{
    $('#standard-clip').fadeOut(300, function(){
        $(this).attr('src','http://cdn.embed.ly/providers/logos/jsfiddle.png')
        .bind('onreadystatechange load', function(){
            if (this.complete) $(this).fadeIn(300);
        });

    });
}
});
```

So first of all something == something is an asking if it's same(non strict) not =. And that's about everything